# Add a fragment containing Google Maps API V2 in Android Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have been trying to insert a Map in my main activity by inflating the map layout in the fragment and then trying to pass it to the activity through fragment manager. I am getting a Fatal Exception and I am not quite sure if what I am trying to do is doable.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Fragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mMapFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
             fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, mMapFragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my fragment:

```
    package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class RunMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Activity_main (with container as ID) is just a simple FrameLayout, while fragment_main is what you find below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

There might be a few nonsense imports, simply because I have been playing with the code. Thanks.

LOGCAT:

```
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942): Process: com.example, PID: 6942
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:384)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-26 14:01:42.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

SOLVED: 
I have removed the fragment from the xml, inserted it in the activity xml and passed onCreateView (from the fragment class) to the superclass.

Comment: better to post your logcat

Comment: try changing this: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment " or to this: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: I have added the logcat.

Comment: Take a look at my solution

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this would be to specify your activity_main.xml layout as follows:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.RunMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and get rid of the `onCreateView()` in that fragment.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to keep things separated. There should be a way to do it. :\

Comment: What things do you mean?

Comment: I want to have an activity_main.xml and a fragment_main.xml.

Comment: You don't need fragment_main.xml at all, because you're trying to inflate a Fragment into a Fragment, and it's neither allowed, nor makes any sense.

Comment: I am simply trying to inflate the fragment's view in onCreateView, while I am adding the fragment in the main activity. I thought it was possible by looking at other samples online. There should be a way to decide which fragment to add to the fragment manager, without inserting the fragment in the main xml. Am I wrong?

Comment: In this case you're right, you can instantiate your RunMapFragment in code and use a transaction to add it. The thing is that you don't need to use onCreateView() in a MapFragment, unless you're trying to decorate the MapView in some way.

Comment: Yes, I also want to decorate, that was the second step if I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your map's id is `R.id.map`, and you're trying to find one called `R.id.container`, that's the `NullPointerException`.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
mMapFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
```

Also, I'm pretty sure that if you declare a `Fragment` via XML, you can't do transactions with it. You should read more on the documentation.

**Edit:** As I said, you can't do transactions with fragments added via XML. You just place them in the `Activity`'s XML and that's it. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html in the section **Adding a fragment to an activity**

Comment: The R.id.container is the MainActivity.xml id.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the fragment, you can't `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container)` to find a fragment, you should use `R.id.map`.

Comment: I have tryied something like this, but it's still not working:        `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mMapFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          fm.beginTransaction()
           .add(R.id.container, mMapFragment)
           .commit();
        }`

Comment: You cant do `beginTransaction()` if the fragment is declared in XML. I updated my post so you have a reference to read on how do you do this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have seen doing what I am trying to do without a fragment tag.

Comment: so, what layout should I inflate in the fragment subclass?

Comment: In your `Activity` layout you should have `<fragment>`. Then forget about `beginTransaction()`. Finally, inflate a different layout for your `Fragment`, call it `R.layout.my_fragment` and declare your `TextViews`, `ImageViews`, etc inside.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have anything to define in my_fragment, that's just the Map.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
mMapFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("Map");
```

and also put this checking. At the start your fragment is null because it is not started and therefore you cannot find it by id.

```
if (mMapFragment != null) {
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, mMapFragment, "Map")
        .commit();
} else {
    mMapFragment = new RunMapFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, mMapFragment, "Map")
        .commit();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe id is making problem, so add tags to your fragments and use findFragmentByTag like in my edited code (also when calling .add use tag "Map").

Also, change your xml fragment by putting:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

instead of:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Comment: I get the same, really weird.

Comment: Try with new changes i made.

Comment: Christopher was saying below that I can't do beginTransaction if the fragment is declared outside of the main_activity.xml. Is that the problem?

Comment: I have app which has separate xml for activity and for fragment. In activity onCreate i do setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and then i add fragment like you do. In fragment i made onCreateView just like yours. So, I think he is wrong

Comment: Try one more thing, put in your xml in fragment tag: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" instead of android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: It really doesn't work, I am not sure if I can inflate a <fragment> layout from the fragment class. :\

Comment: What was the problem?